# Canon 70D max supported SD card size

Tags: canon, sdcard, canon-70d, memory-card-size

I've just went through the Canon 70D manual and couldn't find any reference regarding the supported SD card sizes.

Is there a max supported size limit for the 70D?

I want to purchase a 256GB card and wonder if the camera will be able to handle that card size.
I couldn't find any references online regarding the 70D that card size.

Comment: Why would you rather purchase one 256GB card rather than, say, two 128Gb card or four 64GB cards? If your one 256GB card craps out on you, you lose all of your storage capacity. If one of four 64GB cards fails, you still have 75% of your starting capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used my 70D with a PNY Elite 256GB SDxC card without any problems. I've been using a 128GB version before for quiet awhile without any problems also.

Answer (score 5):

I just took a very quick look at the online manual, and right there on page 3, it says:

> Compatible Cards
>
> The camera can use the following cards **regardless of capacity**:
>
> - SD memory cards
> - SDHC memory cards*
> - SDXC memory cards*
>
> *UHS-I cards supported.

I would advise having a read through the [Wikipedia article on SD cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card). Card capacities are not the main factor in determining compatibility. SD cards have gone through a number of generations – SD (SDSC), SDHC, SDXC, SDUC – and newer generations are not necessarily backwards-compatible. There are also different bus interfaces – Default Speed, High Speed, UHS-I, UHS-II, UHS-III, SD Express.

There is additionally this relevant FAQ on the Canon website:
[What Memory Cards can be used with the camera? (EOS 70D)](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos_70d.html?type=faq&search=1&searchurl=/support/consumer_products/content/faq/?itemid=tcm:14-1076310)

If the card you are considering fulfils the compatibility criteria that Canon mentions, then I see no reason why you should continue to assume incompatibility.

Comment: That's exactly what I've seen in the manual, but this manual is 7+ years old; 256GB/1TB weren't "a thing" back then. Maybe there are some hardware/software/firmware limitations with regard to SD card sizes that weren't considered as a viable option back then.

Comment: The purpose of specs is to provide some compatibility baselines.  If the camera and card both meet the spec, they *should* work together.  There's always the possibility that a particular card from a specific manufacturer may not work properly.  The only way to find out is to try.

Comment: With Canon, as long as the *type* is compatible (SDHC, SDXC, etc.), at worst the camera may only "see" a very large card as having a smaller than actual capacity. If you put a 256GB card in it *might* only "see" 128GB or 64GB, etc.

Comment: @MichaelC I see, thanks for the input.